# reset password show password reset but when try to login again it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, yii

Hello I tried to put forgot password on my web but I have a little problem. I can send the mail to the person who want to reset their password but when the person resets their password it shows password reset but when I try to login with the new password it doesn't work. Only the old one works. Here is my reset.php file:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_GET['action']))
{          
if($_GET['action']=="reset")
{
    $encrypt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['encrypt']);
    $query = "SELECT id FROM user where md5(90*13+id)='".$encrypt."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(count($Results)>=1)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'Invalid key please try again. <a href="http://ocelleslsf.inshea.fr/ocelles/make/fg/#forget">Forget Password?</a>';
    }
    }
    }
     elseif(isset($_POST['action']))
     {

    $encrypt   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['action']);
    $password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
   $query = "SELECT id FROM user where md5(90*13+id)='".$encrypt."'";
   //echo $query;
  $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if(count($Results)>=1)
   {
    $query = "update user set password='".md5($password)."' where id='".$Results['id']."'";
    mysqli_query($connection,$query);
     //        echo $query;
    $message = "Votre mot de passe changé avec succès <a href=\"http://ocelleslsf.inshea.fr/ocelles/\">Cliquez ici pour vous identifier</a>.";
}
else
{
    $message = 'Clé non valide se il vous plaît essayer à nouveau. <a href="http://ocelleslsf.inshea.fr/ocelles/make/fg/#forget">Mot De Passe Oublié?</a>';
}
}
else
{
header("location: /ocelles/make/fg");
 }


 $content ='<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js">  </script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  input[type=password]
  {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width:200px;
  min-height: 28px;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
   }
  input[type=password]:focus
 {
  width: 400px;
  border-color: #51a7e8;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),0 0 5px rgba(81,167,232,0.5);
  outline: none;
  }
  </style>  
   <script>
   $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   });
   function mypasswordmatch()
   {
     var pass1 = $("#password").val();
     var pass2 = $("#password2").val();
     if (pass1 != pass2)
      {
       alert("Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas");
       return false;
     }
      else
       {
         $( "#reset" ).submit();
       }
      }
      </script>
       </head>
        <body>
       <b>'.$message.'</b>
        <div id="tabs" style="width: 480px;">
         <ul>
         <li><a href="#tabs-1">Réinitialiser mot de passe</a></li>


          </ul>                 
         <div id="tabs-1">
         <form action="reset.php" method="post" id="reset" >
          <p><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Entrez nouveau mot de passe">
          <p><input id="password2" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="Retaper nouveau mot de passe">
           <input name="action" type="hidden" value="'.$encrypt.'" /></p>
           <p><input type="button" value="Réinitialiser mot de passe" onclick="mypasswordmatch();" /></p>
          </form>
          </div>
      </div>';


      $pre = 1;
       $title = "How to create Login and Signup form in PHP";
       $heading = "How to create Login and Signup form in PHP.";
        include("html.inc");            
         ?>
```

Comment: Your form sends a `POST` but I think you are requiring a `GET` at the start `if(isset($_GET['action']))`? Your indentation is off so can't be sure about that...

Comment: *change this (MD5) to this `password_hash()`* ;-)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: fred no there is no error. i think the problem is because of encrypted password. i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string` to sanitize and to escape special characters on `$encrypt`, but this string may have special characters. Make sure if `mysqli_real_escape_string` function isn't removing any character from `$encrypt` value.

Comment: the problem is it's not changing the password from database. Please can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this part of your code is doing:

```
...} elseif(isset($_POST['action'])) {

  $encrypt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['action']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
  $query = "SELECT id FROM user where md5(90*13+id)='".$encrypt."'";
  //echo $query;
  $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  $Results = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if(count($Results)>=1) {
    $query = "update user set password='".md5($password)."' where id='".$Results['id']."'";
    mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $message = "Votre mot de passe changé avec succès <a href=\"http://ocelleslsf.inshea.fr/ocelles/\">Cliquez ici pour vous identifier</a>.";
}...
```

Seems like you're trying to match the user id with `$_POST['action']` encrypted and probably not finding any match on database.

Comment: yes when it send the message it send that it's your user id and it's link to reset password. User id which it send is right but when i reset i don't understand what happens. If you have any idea.